# Set a variable equal to result if result exists

Tags: python

This seems very verbose, particularly with long function names, is there a better way to do this in Python?

```
if someRandomFunction():
    variable = someRandomFunction()
```

**Edit:** For more context variable is not already defined, and it will be a new node on a tree. I only want to create this node if someRandomFunction() returns a value. And someRandomFunction() is supposed to return the string representation of some node from a different type of tree.

Comment: why can't you just do var = someFunc() and then check var for None?

Comment: WHy would you **ever** leave the variable undefined?  What possible reason can you give for this?  `variable = someRandomFunction()` makes sense.  The `if` statement makes no sense at all.  Please provide a reason why you'd leave a variable undefined!

Comment: @jawonlee: Presumably `variable` should be unchanged if `someRandomFunction()` returns a falsy value.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Not sure I'm buying that from the example (and text) provided.  However, it's possible... but it sounds silly.

Comment: To add some context, I'm querying an XML tree and adding the values to a to another tree of a different type. I don't want to create an empty node on the second tree if there isn't a value on the first.

Comment: @Colin Barnes: In which case, you need to update your question to more accurately reflect your algorithm.  The comment and the question's code sample don't make much sense together.

Answer (score 16):

Could you:

```
variable = someRandomFunction() or variable
```

See [Boolean Operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in the Python documentation for more information.

Comment: It's not clear from the question as stated whether `variable` is defined yet before this line of code gets executed. If `someRandomFunction()` evaluates to False, this raises a NameError exception because variable isn't defined yet.

Comment: @ma3204: I think we have to assume it's already defined, because if it's not and `someRandomFunction` returns false, then any code that used `variable` afterwards would also result in a `NameError` in the original code.

Comment: I don't see how we can assume it has been defined from the question as stated-- that is exactly my point and (I believe) the same point S. Lott has been trying to make. Nor can we assume that the variable needs to be defined after this point in the code if the function returns a False value. S. Lott's answer most accurately reflects the answer to the question asked.

Comment: In my particular case variable doesn't exist before hand and it will simply be checked if the node exists on a tree.

Answer (score 6):

```
temp= someRandomFunction()
if temp:
    variable = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit unorthodox perhaps, but you could modify `someRandomFunction()` so that it saves its last result in a function attribute before returning it, you could then do this.

```
def someRandomFunction():
    ...
    someRandomFunction.result = <...>
    return someRandomFunction.result

if someRandomFunction():
    variable = someRandomFunction.result
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your answer is too verbose. It says exactly what it does. However, since you've already said it's too verbose for your tastes I would opt for the

s = myFunc() or someVariable

approach